# Android Studio - Navigation Editor not showing previews after using amplify sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, aws-amplify-sdk-android

Suddenly the preview of the navigation graph just dissapear. After a deep research I figure out this problem was triggered right after adding the amplify dependency.

To reproduce this bug, follow the following steps:

1. Clone the repository https://github.com/rchampa/NavigationXMLBug
2. Go to :sharedlibrary build.gradle file and change from:
   `implementation('com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.33.0')`
   to
   `api('com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.33.0')`
3. Open the the nav_grap.xml file located in app/anyfeature/res/navigation
4. If you don't see the result as is described in the picture bellow then restart android studio.
5. The bug is about I cannot see the preview of the nav_graph.xml however I still can use the code section but is anoying see nothing in the preview.

[image]